# Not able to SSH into the EC2Instance with Jenkins installed

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, ssh, jenkins-cli

After creating a fresh EC2 server machine, I am able to SSH into it.
From this SSH session, I am able to install the required software to run Jenkins on it.
I am able to make basic pipelines and do standard work on the Jenkins which is running perfectly fine.

Below are the commands I am using to setup the Jenkins on the machine-

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y openjdk-11-jdk

sudo apt install -y maven
sudo apt install unzip wget

wget -p -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins.io.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo deb http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y jenkins

sudo systemctl start jenkins
sudo ufw allow 8080
sudo ufw enable
sudo cat /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword
```

After this, if I close the SSH session and try to reconnect to the EC2, I am not able to do so.

The SSH is possible only before installing the Jenkins.
Is Jenkins somehow disabling the SSH login into machine?
I am new to this and could use some help.

Jenkins Version - Jenkins 2.357
EC2 - Ubuntu 20.04
Sec Groups - Allows All Traffic
plugins installed - Default suggested plugins at startup

Comment: It would appear that your `ufw` firewall is blocking the SSH connection. Could you use the EC2 security group to protect your instance instead of `ufw`? Alternatively, try allowing port 22 too.

Comment: Thanks a lot @John .
I added `sudo ufw allow 22` (after the `sudo ufw allow 8080`) while configuring the firewall post installation & it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/174777/john-rotenstein) in the comments, I added `sudo ufw allow 22` after installing the jenkins to allowing the traffic.

Also, the gpg keys for the installation of the Jenkins got outdated.
The fresh steps for installation of Jenkins can be found [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/linux/#debianubuntu).